# Misspelled Tag (Robotc)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I found this misspelled tag - https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tags/robotc/info.

It is supposed to say "robotic".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [robotc](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robotc) tag refers to a specific programming environment.

I have updated the [tag wiki](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tags/robotc/info) to explain this.

All questions should be related to robotic systems, so a [robotic](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robotic) tag would serve no purpose.

Comment: That is interesting to know. I have never heard of the robotc environment. Thank you.

Comment: A google search for `robotc` or a look at the questions tagged with [tag:robotc] would have shown what the tag was intended for too.

Comment: True, but when I first saw that tag, I falsely assumed that it was a misspelling.